# Heroku crash - Python script execution exited with status 0

Tags: python, docker, heroku

I'm using Docker to deploy a Python script that opens a web page using selenium and firefox in [id.heroku.com](https://id.heroku.com), but when I execute it, it crashes with exit code 0:

[image]

This is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:stretch
# Install git, supervisor, VNC, & X11 packages
RUN set -ex; \
    apt-get update; \
    apt-get -y install firefox-esr; \
COPY . /app
RUN chmod +x /app/conf.d/websockify.sh
RUN chmod +x /app/script.py
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/entrypoint.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "/app/script.py"]
```

This is the Script.py:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import FirefoxOptions

opts = FirefoxOptions()
opts.add_argument("--headless")
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=opts)

browser.get('http://example.com')
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: It looks like your script simply runs some code, then finishes. Exiting 0 (with indicates _success_, not failure) is what I'd expect it to do. What do _you_ expect? Please read [ask].

Comment: Yes, it runs perfectly, but it crashes

Comment: But it is a short script that only requests one single URL. It probably finishes in a second or two. What do you expect it to be doing in, say, an hour? (Again, exiting with status 0 generally does _not_ indicate a crash. Nothing went wrong, the script simply finished.)

Comment: I want to enter in my web page after the python script gets some info of the URL requested: 'http://example.com'

Comment: What do you mean by "enter in my web page"? I'm not very familiar with Selenium, but I think this script just loads `http://example.com` in memory and then finishes. Do you intend to do something with the page that lives at `http://example.com`?

Comment: The thing is that I want to get some info of example.com with a python script, but if I run that python script, my web (the web hosted in heroku) stops working,

Comment: (a) But your script _doesn't_ do anything with `example.com`. It just stops. Are you planning to add more code after `browser.get('http://example.com')`? (b) If you're not planning to run a web server, don't run a `web` process. I think you want a `worker`.